# ListPicker issue in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listpicker

```
   long stdid;
    string stdname;


    public long studentId
    {
        get { return stdid; }
        set { stdid = value; }
    }

    public string studentName
    {
        get { return stdname; }
        set { stdname = value; }
    }
```

how do I show my listpikcer with by default selected item "SELECT",
my listpicker is binded with,

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding}"
```

I have not added items manually in listpicker, items come from class,
so, how to solve it?

Comment: okay share your class definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new List of your class type

```
List<MyClass> myList=new List<MyClass>();
```

and add one item of your class type somewhat like this:

```
myList.Add(new MyClass(){studentName="Please Select, StudentId=0"});
```

now add the items of your class list in this new list

```
foreach(var item in oldList)
{
myList.add(item);
}
```

after this loop assign myList as the itemsource to the listpicker and check.

```
listpicker.ItemSource=myList;
listpicker.SelectedIndex=0;
```